"invalid type (list) for variable 'Return_Data_for_R_regression[, i + 1]" Error in R
I want to get a residual from a regression. This is a Youtube video that i watch that i want to replicate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjCs6eAdzn0&t=537s . (the code that he uses are attached below)
After i tried to replicate it, the result showed an error that says "Error in model.frame.default(formula = Return_Data_for_R_regression[,  :
invalid type (list) for variable 'Return_Data_for_R_regression[, i + 1]'"
Here is the code that the Youtuber uses:
#import the data file
crash_sata <- read_csv("dummycsv.csv", header=T)

#initialize the residual matrix to a null matrix, the size is based on the size of the output data
Residuals_expanded_model<-matrix(0,517,100)

#generate the residuals matrix using the expanded matrix model
for (i in 1:100) {
  Residuals_expanded_model[,i]<-resid(lm(crash_data[,i+1] ~ crash_data[,102]+ crash_data[,103]+ crash_data[,104]+ crash_data[,105]+ crash_data[,106]))
}

#calculate the firm specific weekly returns as log of 1 plus the residual term from the expanded market model
firm_spe_week_retur<-log(matrix(1,517,100)+Residuals_expanded_model)

#export data
write.csv(firm_spe_week_retur,"returns_W.csv")

**Meanwhile, this is the code that i use:
**
Return_Data_for_R_regression <- read_csv("~/Skripsi/Return Data for R regression.csv")
View(Return_Data_for_R_regression)

Residuals_expanded_model<-matrix(0,374,47)

for (i in 1:47) {
  Residuals_expanded_model[,i]<-resid(lm(Return_Data_for_R_regression[,i+1] ~ Return_Data_for_R_regression[,49]+ Return_Data_for_R_regression[,50]+ Return_Data_for_R_regression[,51]+ Return_Data_for_R_regression[,52]+ Return_Data_for_R_regression[,53]))
}

firm_spe_week_retur<-log(matrix(1,374,47)+Residuals_expanded_model)

write.csv(firm_spe_week_retur,"returns_W.csv")

This is the data that i used for the regression: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yx2R374c3dY-SwqEk7_xKUXjyhQn6YbE/view?usp=sharing
Please help me find out what causes the error and how to fix it, thank you.
